# do all tables of the mysql db have to have same encoding?

Tags: mysql

I just switched to utf-8 for more characters, but I only store user posts in a couple of tables which I needed utf-8 for. Should I for some reason change all the tables to utf-8? Should I not?

Comment: there's no rule about it but it's a good habit. consistency is always good ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each table in a MySQL database can specify its own encoding. However, unless there is a real need for different encodings, it is a good idea to keep them all the same and avoid any subtle errors in the future as you (or future developers) forget that this table is in *that* encoding and the other table isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to have the same character set across all tables.  Having said this it can cause issues when you join across tables with different character sets as indexes cannot be compared.  For this reason alone I'd recommend that you keep the same character sets across your tables.